# How to remove extra space (nbsp) at the of every line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

So I have received this film script which has one or two extra spaces at the end of every line.
I want to remove extra space from the end of every line in notepadd++ but keep the spaces between the words. is there any way I can do this? there are more than 2000 lines.

**so if the line goes:**

```
Hii, My name is john, and I work at a cafe.[nbsp]
Hii, My name is john, and I work at a cafe.[nbsp][nbsp]
Hii, My name is john, and I work at a cafe.[nbsp]
Hii, My name is john, and I work at a cafe.[nbsp][nbsp]
```

**I want it like:**

```
Hii, My name is john, and I work at a cafe.
Hii, My name is john, and I work at a cafe.
Hii, My name is john, and I work at a cafe.
Hii, My name is john, and I work at a cafe.
```

Comment: Is it simple space or `[nbsp]` ?

Comment: - [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
 - [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
 - [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
 - [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: not simple space. it is [nbsp]

Comment: remove all spaces before `\r\n`

Answer (score 3):

Use `\h` that stands for any horizontal space, including `nbsp`.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\h+$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

`\h+$` matches any number of horizontal spaces at the end of a line.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple when using regex.

Find what : `( | )+$` (note the starting blank and the special character)
Replace with : (nothing)
Check : "Regular expression"

Note that the characters inside the `( | )` part are : a blank,
`|` and a non-breaking space that is typed as
`ALT + 0,1,6,0` on the numeric keypad.

Explanation : Replace any number of blanks followed by an end-of-line
with nothing, meaning deleting them.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that matches a nbsp?

Comment: @DavidPostill: Not sure, so answer modified.

Comment: Regexp should allow `( | )` to be replaced by `[  \xa0]` (single spaces!) as produced by windows'y character typing (on a Swedish keyboard); AltGr+8, space, Alt (keep down) 0 1 6 0 (let go of Alt), AltGr+9. Depending on the regexp version used in Notepad++ a `\s+$` might also do the same. -> https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

Comment: @Hannu: I tried it after I saw your answer, but it didn't work for me on Notepad++.

Comment: Ok. **Verified to be invalid** there then.

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing even the basics of Notepad++

Search for regex `\xa0+\x0a` and replace with `\0x0a` i.e.

Any number of (as by regex +) NBSP with a following LF and replace by just LF.

*Now if that is on Mac or Windows, you might need to replace `\x0a` with `\0x0d` - to get anywhere, as those OS's has it "backwards" in some sense.*

*Now, please do read the comments below to get to grips with the **actual value** of this answer.*

Comment: It's more that windows uses `\r\n` whereas Mac & nix only use `\n`

Comment: Mac has at least historically used `\r`, maybe it changed to be *nix'y somewhere in time.

Comment: System 9 & earlier. They transitioned to the nix method 20 years ago, as they transitioned to a nix underpinning, with 'OS X'.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that, as I considered it to be a flaw and disregarded the OS based on  that among other heavy facts, in that time.

Comment: The 'flaw' if any, is on Windows still hanging onto both CR & LF, as though we all were still using line-feed printers or teletype ;))

Comment: Agreed, the "flaw" was in MacOs _then_ ;-)

Comment: There was no standard at the time. Mac picked one way, unix another & Win an awkward third. There is no right & wrong in that. Mac & nix at least agreed that there was no longer any need for *both*.

Comment: Yes; no right or wrong in that, beyond the fact that nobody considered the benefit of having standards, and work for getting one defined, instead of just winging it. <- i.e. that is the 'root cause' of the flaw.

Comment: So, if anything, we should point the finger at MS for hanging onto an outmoded method everyone else agreed to simplify 20 years ago ;)

Comment: *lol* yes. Do that! ;-)

Comment: I'm glad we got that one ironed out ;)))

Comment: Use `$` which is the anchor for end of a line - avoids the need to specify EOL characters. Or `\R` which will match any EOL characters.

Comment: Well, that is a "work around" ;-)

Comment: Now, for the person voting down; this answer might not be the best as for the "final" solution, but the fact that it remains here will most certainly enlighten on what the edited file actually contains; and that might be required as a lead forward to the best solution.